# Doctor Skarosa?

Tags: doctor-who

What is the meaning of the name **Dr. Skarosa** in the two-parter *Dark Water / Death in Heaven*?

I mean, the similarities between this name and **Skaro** are too great to be a coincidence.

> So I assumed it was just a red herring, to throw people off who hadn't seen the trailer yet.
> But then there was a dark water cell with his name on it. And when the cells activated, he reanimated subsequently and got obliterated by Danny Pink (at least according to the [Tardis Data Core](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Skarosa); I didn't actually catch that). So he was a real person. Then the question remains...

How did he come by this name?

Comment: I'm assuming you're not interested in the obvious "THE MOFF intended the name as a red herring" answer, because I fear that will be all there is to that... or it will come up again in a year or two....

Comment: Haha! Exactly! And that's why I'm asking.

Comment: That's a nice catch. Can't believe I missed it...

Comment: Who knows.... Maybe there _was_ a Dalek inside that cyber-armour.... One would never know.... Daleks live inside an armour anyways.... Surely The Mistress could've modified a cyber-armour to be operated by a Dalek.....

Comment: I finally remembered to come back and update my answer in light of Series 9. Still seems to be just a red herring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **It was a red herring.**

Moffat sneaked at least two red herrings into the episode *Dark Water*, for the true Who nerds to pick up on and begin speculating before the final reveal. The term "Random Access Neural Interface" for Missy, and the name Doctor Skarosa that you're asking about, suggested the **Rani** and the **Daleks** respectively as the episode's secret mastermind(s). All of this to divert attention from perhaps the greatest Doctor Who villain of all,

> the **Master**.

You can read speculation about it [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/gallifrey/comments/2l5ckk/so_about_doctor_skarosa/) and [here](http://forums.digitalspy.co.uk/showthread.php?t=2022020), but there seems to be no official confirmation that it was just a red herring...

**yet**.

In series 9,

> Missy came back, but we learned nothing more about her history with 3W. However, she seemed shocked and horrified to discover that Skaro had returned, and she didn't seem to be in league with Davros and the Daleks, poking Davros in the eye as a parting shot.

We could speculate about Missy having given Dr Skarosa his name in honour of the greatest enemy of the Time Lord race, but then we'd *really* be overthinking things. Basically, it's just a red herring.

Comment: Damn it, I missed the RANI acronym too

Comment: Oh... Well, OK then.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a link between Daleks and Dr. Skarosa.
Daleks were created in Skaro by Davros (as anyone knows) and they are the ultimate racist race in Universe.

Because of this racism, it looks impossible that The Mistress modified a cyber-armor to be operated by a Dalek 'cause the Dalek can't be something else than a Dalek.
We can see it when Rose accidentally reborn a Dalek : he prefers death than life with no Dalek's wishes.

So, in my mind, it's only a Moff-thing. I know that it's not the answer you want, but it's the most logical... Sorry ^^

Comment: This seems very "opinion-y" without anything to back it up.